# Showing a content on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have four floated divs with same width and height.

In between each div there is a content div hidden and related to the floated div.

While I hover over any of the floated divs the corresponding div 
content will be shown, and on mouseout it will go back to its original position.

How can i achieve this using jquery?

Please follow the following link for code sample http://jsfiddle.net/NbVfD/22/

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
$('.box').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).next('.boxTxt').show();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).next('.boxTxt').hide();
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NbVfD/23/).

Updating the above to include `fadeIn()`/`fadeOut()` animations:

```
$('.box').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).next('.boxTxt').stop().fadeIn(900);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).next('.boxTxt').stop().fadeOut(900);
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NbVfD/52/).

And amend your HTML so you're using `class` instead of `id` to identify your elements, as:

> `id` = name [CS]
>
> > This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.
>
> `class` = cdata-list [CS]
>
> > This attribute assigns a class name or set of class names to an element. Any number of elements may be assigned the same class name or names. Multiple class names must be separated by white space characters.

(Quoted from: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

Of course, you could achieve much the same with simple CSS:

```
.box:hover + .boxTxt,
.boxTxt:hover {
    display: block; /* to show the element */
    width: 10em; /* aesthetics, adjust to taste... */
    height: 20em;
    background-color: #ffa;
    overflow: hidden; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin-left: -10px;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NbVfD/26/).

Updated the above to allow for CSS transitions (where available) to animate the reveal/un-reveal of the elements (I've also changed the HTML a little, for this):

```
#boxCon {width:100%}
.boxTxt{
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em; /* in order that there was a target area on the next .boxWrap to
                 to provide a :hover target area to mouse-over to trigger the
                 next .boxTxt to reveal */
    left: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;}

.box{width:50px; height:50px; background-color:#000; 
}

.boxWrap:hover .boxTxt{
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    width: 10em;
    height: 20em;
    background-color: #ffa;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

div.boxWrap {
    float: left; /* as originally assigned to .box elements */
    padding: 20px 5px; /* equal to the margins originally placed on the .box elements */
    position: relative; /* to allow for absolute positioning of the .boxTxt elements */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NbVfD/54/).

References:

- [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).
- [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
- [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

Comment: can this achieve by using animate() method? (ie) the box should appear slowly. Even we can use click method instead of hover.

Comment: @Yesvinkumar: I've updated the answer with animation/transition. Hopefully they should work for you. =)

Comment: Thank you david for your demo. This is what i am looking for. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Use mouseenter() & mouseleave function to achieve this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
div.out {
width:40%;
height:120px;
margin:0 15px;
background-color:#D6EDFC;
float:left;
}
div.in {
width:60%;
height:60%;
background-color:#FFCC00;
margin:10px auto;
}
p {
line-height:1em;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="out overout"><p>move your mouse</p><div class="in overout"><p>move your mouse</p><p>0</p></div><p>0</p></div>

<div class="out enterleave"><p>move your mouse</p><div class="in enterleave"><p>move your mouse</p><p>0</p></div><p>0</p></div>


<script>
    var i = 0;
    $("div.overout").mouseover(function(){
      $("p:first",this).text("mouse over");
    }).mouseout(function(){
      $("p:first",this).text("mouse out");
      $("p:last",this).text(++i);
    });

    var n = 0;
    $("div.enterleave").mouseenter(function(){
      $("p:first",this).text("mouse enter");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
      $("p:first",this).text("mouse leave");
      $("p:last",this).text(++n);
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Ref URL: http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

(mark as answer if you find it correct.)

Answer (score 0):

See the working example :

http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/4HvH3/

**HTML**

```
<div id="boxCon">

    <div class="box" data-img="boxTxt1"></div>
    <div id="boxTxt1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>

    <div class="box" data-img="boxTxt2"></div>
    <div id="boxTxt2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>

</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$("#boxCon").on("mouseover mouseout", "div.box", function () {
    $("#" + $(this).data("img")).toggle();
});
```